# Strange Analyze results Function call argument is an uninitialized value

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i analyze my project i'm getting strange error function call arument is an uninitialized value , i searched lot but not get any solution  , i'm using this code . Thanks for your effort

Getting problem on last line

```
rect = CGRectMake(ceilf(rect.origin.x), ceilf(rect.origin.y), ceilf(rect.size.width), ceilf(rect.size.height));
```

**Code**

```
CGRect rect;
if (self.segmentWidthStyle == HMSegmentedControlSegmentWidthStyleFixed) 
{
          rect = CGRectMake((self.segmentWidth * idx) + (self.segmentWidth - stringWidth) / 2, y, stringWidth, stringHeight);
          rectDiv = CGRectMake((self.segmentWidth * idx) - (self.verticalDividerWidth / 2), self.selectionIndicatorHeight * 2, self.verticalDividerWidth, self.frame.size.height - (self.selectionIndicatorHeight * 4));
          fullRect = CGRectMake(self.segmentWidth * idx, 0, self.segmentWidth, oldRect.size.height);

} 
else if (self.segmentWidthStyle == HMSegmentedControlSegmentWidthStyleDynamic) 
{

// When we are drawing dynamic widths, we need to loop the widths array to calculate the xOffset

CGFloat xOffset = 0;
NSInteger i = 0;
for (NSNumber *width in self.segmentWidthsArray) 
{
    if (idx == i)
    break;
    xOffset = xOffset + [width floatValue];
    i++;
}

CGFloat widthForIndex = [[self.segmentWidthsArray objectAtIndex:idx] floatValue];
rect = CGRectMake(xOffset, y, widthForIndex, stringHeight);
fullRect = CGRectMake(self.segmentWidth * idx, 0, widthForIndex, oldRect.size.height);
rectDiv = CGRectMake(xOffset - (self.verticalDividerWidth / 2), self.selectionIndicatorHeight * 2, self.verticalDividerWidth, self.frame.size.height - (self.selectionIndicatorHeight * 4));
            }

 // Fix rect position/size to avoid blurry labels
  rect = CGRectMake(ceilf(rect.origin.x), ceilf(rect.origin.y), ceilf(rect.size.width), ceilf(rect.size.height));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing rect to ceilf while it may not by initialized if both ifs will fail. Change of first line to `CGRect rect = CGRectZero;` will fix the warning, however I am not sure that it is behavior that you may  want.

Comment: When i add this facing another error Passed-by-value struct argument contains uninitialized data (e.g., via the field chain: 'origin.x')

Comment: @suthar Actually replace whole line that cause error to rect = CGRectIntegral(rect); it does the same as your code line

Comment: @suthar is this warning still happening with alternated last line?

Comment: I'll check and then let you know